# KML/KMZ google maps from a c# windows program

Tags: google-maps

Can an unhosted KML/KMZ file be sent to Google Maps from a C# Windows program? Essentially, I want to send a KML/KMZ file directly to Google Maps instead of sending a URL pointing back to a public server containing the KML file.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Not to Google Maps or to the Google Maps API v3 native [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer), for that the URL needs to be "hosted on a publicly accessible web server."

If you use a third party parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) [and possibly [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)), you can use a local file (depending on the browser security policy) or even a string containing valid KML.

geoxml3 supports KMZ, but whether it will work from a local filesystem depends on the browser.

The disadvantage of using a third party parser is you lose the performance advantage of the tiled rendering that you get if using KmlLayer.

You might also investigate using Google Earth (but you didn't include that in your tags)

Comment: Good answer. But please be aware that - by using a JS based KML interpreter - you loose one great advantage of KmlLayers of the Maps API: With such layers your KML files can be very complex without any performance repercussions. The KML files are read and cached by Google servers and are transformed into PNGs that are sent back to the maps stage div of the visitor. This absorbs all complexity that might be contained in the KML "artwork".

Comment: Thanks, meant to say something about that. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and suggetions. I think I'm on the right track. Very helpful and appreciated.